# Diagonalization is influenced by the degree of minimal and characteristic polinomial?

Tags: polynomials, diagonalization, minimal-polynomials

As in the title, lets say i have a matrix wich have the characteristic poyinomial with degree  $(n)$  and lets say the degree of his minimal polynomial is $(n-1)$. This fact influence the possibilities of diagonalization?

And if the polynomials have the same degree? This tell us something about we can or not diagonalize those matrices?

I will say... ...no. In both cases. I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, "no" is correct.  The exception are $n=1$ and  $n=2$: 
if the characteristic polynomial has degree $1$ or 
if the minimal polynomial has degree $1$, the matrix is certainly diagonalizable.

Over the complex numbers, a matrix is diagonalizable iff its minimal polynomial has all roots distinct.

The characteristic polynomial of an $n \times n$ matrix has degree $n$.
Thus if there are $k$ distinct eigenvalues (roots of the characteristic polynomial), the matrix is diagonalizable iff the minimal polynomial has
degree $k$.  But $k$ could be anywhere from $1$ to $n$.

Comment: Ok, but i dont get why it happens for n=2 and not for n>2. Its linked to the fact we have max 2 informations by the 2 polynomials? The only think i know is that the roots of the characteristic polinomial are the eigenvalues of our matrix and if $dim E(v) =M_a (v)$ i can diagonalize the matrix.

Comment: So the degree of the minimal polynomial is linked to the $M_a(v)$ (algebric multeplicity of v)?

Comment: For $n=2$, $n-1 = 1$.  If the minimal polynomial has degree $1$ it has one root (which is trivially distinct).  So in the case $n=2$ your statement that the minimal polynomial has degree $n-1$ does imply that the matrix is diagonalizable.

Comment: If any eigenvalue has geometric multiplicity different from its algebraic multiplicity, the matrix is not diagonalizable.  The degree of the minimal polynomial is the sum over eigenvalues of the size of the largest block for that eigenvalue in the Jordan normal form.  The geometric multiplicity of an eigenvalue is the number of Jordan blocks for that eigenvalue, while the algebraic multiplicity is the sum of the sizes of those blocks.  In order for the matrix to be diagonalizable, all blocks must be of size $1$.